# website is loading page not found error via nginx

Tags: nginx

We have setup a nginx server with the following configuration but when trying to access the domain it is giving the . Nginx is installed on debian 10 machine

```
Error 404: Not found :-(
THe web server is not configured to handle this request. Are you sure you typed in the correct URL?. If yes, please contact the admin.
```

Following is the configuration of the nginx file

```
server {
                listen          80;
                server_name     domain_name ;
                root /var/www;

               
        }
```

Permissions for /var/www is set correctly. Still not able to acecss the domain name . Please help here

Comment: Can you show the access log and error log entries corresponding to the request?

Comment: access log is empty and error log does not have any logs for the domain name mentioned in my above config. Error logs shows ```2021/12/08 12:23:33 [notice] 183910#183910: signal process started```

Comment: That message does not look like a default Nginx 404 response, and the lack of evidence from logfiles suggests that your Nginx server did not generate it.

Comment: Does it mean that nginx was installed correctly ?